# Trying two different methods to transform a picture - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, transform

So Im still learning Java. Now Im learning JavaFX.

I have a picture of a tree. And I want to try two different method. the first method I use was using unary operator to turn the image colour to grey.

Now I want to try a second method using the `ColourTransformer` interface that I made to get a 10 pixel wide gray frame replacing the pixels on the border of an image.

This is what I have done. for the second method, im not quite sure how to specify the pixel. Any suggestions?

this is what I have done

```
public class ColourFilter extends Application {

   //Using Unary Operator to transform image to grayscale - Method 1
   public static Image transform(Image in, UnaryOperator<Color> f) {
      int width = (int) in.getWidth();
      int height = (int) in.getHeight();
      WritableImage out = new WritableImage(
              width, height);
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            out.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, y,
                    f.apply(in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y)));
      return out;
   }
   public static <T> UnaryOperator<T> compose(UnaryOperator<T> op1, UnaryOperator<T> op2) {
      return t -> op2.apply(op1.apply(t));
   }

   //Using ColourTransformer interface to get 10 pixel wide gray frame replacing the pixels on the border of an image - Method 2
   public static Image transform(Image in, ColourTransformer f) {
      int width = (int) in.getWidth();
      int height = (int) in.getHeight();
      WritableImage out = new WritableImage(
              width, height);
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            out.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, y, f.apply(x, y, in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y)));
      return out;
   }
   @FunctionalInterface
   interface ColourTransformer {
      Color apply(int x, int y, Color colorAtXY);
   }

   public void start(Stage stage) {
      Image image = new Image("amazing-trees.jpg");
      Image image2 = transform(image, Color::brighter);
      Image image3 = transform(image2, Color::grayscale);
      // alternative to two previous image transforms -- composition
      //Image image3 = transform(image, compose(Color::brighter, Color::grayscale));
      stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(
              new ImageView(image),
              // new ImageView(image2),
              new ImageView(image3))));
      stage.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile, does it? In `transform(Image, ColourTransformer)` don't you need `f.apply(x, y, in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y))`? Can you clarify what the question is?

Comment: It doesnt compile when I added the second method in. The first method I made works fine. So the aim of the second method is to use the  `ColourTransformer` interface to get 10 pixel wide gray frame replacing the pixels on the border of an image.

Comment: What's the compile error? Isn't it fixed by the change I suggested above? (BTW, don't you think that including information like "it doesn't compile", along with the compile error you are getting, would make it more likely that someone would be able to answer the question...?)

Comment: Oh yes, noted. Hmm the suggestions that you made was already there all along in the second method. Ill update the error message.

Comment: No, the suggestions I made are not there. You have `f.apply(in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y))`. I think you need `f.apply(x, y, in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y))`. (Which is *exactly* what the error message tells you.)

Comment: Now you removed the call to `setColor(...)`, and the definition of `compose()`. Why did you do that?

Comment: Oh I want to show you so its easier to see?

Comment: But the new compile errors are because you removed the `compose` method. And now your transform method doesn't actually do anything. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Sorry, my apology Ill change it back. I was just thinking, so itll be easier for you to see. thats it

Comment: I can see your code, and could all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compile error message says, you are trying to call

```
f.apply(Color);
```

where `f` is a `ColourTransformer`: however you defined the `apply` method in `ColorTransformer` with three parameters: `apply(int, int, Color)`.

You need to replace

```
f.apply(in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y))
```

with

```
f.apply(x, y, in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y))
```

i.e.

```
public static Image transform(Image in, ColourTransformer f) {
    int width = (int) in.getWidth();
    int height = (int) in.getHeight();
    WritableImage out = new WritableImage(
          width, height);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            out.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, y, f.apply(x, y, in.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y)));
    return out;

}
```

You can get the 10-pixel gray border by doing:

```
Image image = new Image("amazing-trees.jpg");
int width = (int) image.getWidth();
int height = (int) image.getHeight();
Image framedImage = transform(image, (x, y, color) -> {
    if (x < 10 || y < 10 || width - x < 10 || height - y < 10) {
        return Color.GRAY ;
    } else return color ;
});
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I specify it to get a 10 pixel wide gray frame replacing the pixels on the border of the image?